# How do I include the stock item with the product collection

Tags: magento2.4, product-collection, magento2.4.4

In magento-1.9 I would call

```
$Products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$products->setFlag('require_stock_items', true);
```

And this would add the `StockItem` to every product in the collection.

I can't see how to do this in M2, if I instantiate a `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` and call `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status->addStockDataToCollection` it will error out with

```
  "0": "You cannot define a correlation name 'stock_status_index' more than once",
  "1": "#1 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select->_join() called at [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php:357]\n#2 Zend_Db_Select->joinInner() called at [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php:336]\
```

I don't have MSI installed, as I understand it's still optional?